# How to interpret the VtkCamera viewTransformMatrix

Tags: c++, math, opengl, geometry, vtk

I have an object at the origin and am moving the camera to (0,650,650) and setting the focal point to the origin i.e.:

```
vtkSmartPointer<vtkCamera> cam = vtkSmartPointer<vtkCamera>::New();
renderer->SetActiveCamera(cam);

cam->SetFocalPoint(0., 0., 0.);
cam->SetPosition(0., 650, 650);
cam->SetViewAngle(view_angle_);

cam->SetViewUp(0., 1., 0.);
```

However when I get the view transform matrix of the camera by:

```
vtkSmartPointer<vtkMatrix4x4> transform_view = cam->GetViewTransformMatrix();
```

And print it I get the following:

```
| 1 |    0    |    0    |     0    | 
| 0 | cos(45) | -sin(45)|     0    | 
| 0 | sin(45) | cos(45) | -919.239 | 
| 0 |    0    |    0    |     1    |
```

Where the rotation part seems correct (45 degrees around the x axis) but the translation seems all wrong. Should the last column not be:

```
| 0 |
|650|
|650|
```

Or am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 2):

It's an old question, but I'll give an answer for the record.

---

What you expect is the transform *w_T_c*, i.e. from the camera frame to the world frame.

What **GetViewTransformMatrix** method returns, is *c_T_w*, i.e. the transform from the world to the camera frame: given a point in the world frame *p_w*, its coordinates in the camera frame are *p_c = c_T_w * p_w*.

In your example, if you inverted your matrix, in the last column you would get the translation values you were looking for.

Answer (score 0):

The focal point is not the same as the "look at" point.  The focal point may be in front of or behind the camera.  It's the point through which all of the rays of your scene will pass to give your view perspective.  Those rays are projected onto the view plane, which is what is rendered.

If you want to look at the origin, you need to set your View Plane Normal vector to be a normalized vector pointing from your camera location to the origin.  So, if your camera location is at location L, the View Plane Normal vector should be -L/||L|| where || || is the l-2 norm.

Comment: according to the vtk docs (here: http://www.vtk.org/doc/release/5.2/html/a00154.html#40f9e41a86e5b7c94fe171e7b9193673) it says that in the method `GetViewTransformMatrix()` **"The ViewTransform depends on only three ivars: the Position, the FocalPoint, and the ViewUp vector."**

Comment: having a look at the vtkCamera docs the method `SetViewPlaneNormal` has been deprecated. Perhaps you could show some code to achieve this? However, the rotation matrix seems correct so wouldn't that mean the camera is facing the correct point, the origin in this case?

Comment: The documentation says "[the ViewPlaneNormal] methods have been deprecated. The view plane normal is automatically set from the DirectionOfProjection according to the ViewShear." It also says "[the View Plane Normal] will point opposite to the direction of projection, unless you have created an sheared output view using SetViewShear/SetObliqueAngles." So, use the DirectionOfProjection methods instead... in this case then it's just L/||L||.  I don't have any code; I've never used vtk.

Comment: To address your first comment, the documentation also states "[The vtkCamera class] provides methods to position and orient the view point and focal point".  This implies they are treating the view point and the focal point as being generally distinct, consistent with the common usage of both terms.  They may be using the focal point and camera location to (artificially) constrain the camera properties; the documentation I read doesn't make any mention of such constraints, however.  In short I don't see immediately how the two statements in the documentation can be reconciled.